# Minimum of $x_1^2+x_2^4$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

> I am asked to find a minimum of $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2+x_2^4$ applying the optimality conditions.

I am stuck. What I have found is not conclusive. I show what I have done:

### Testing the First-Order Necessary Conditions

I computed the gradient:

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=2x_1 , \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=4x_2^3\right)$
Now when doing:
$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)=0$ I obtain the stationary point $x^*=[0, 0]$.

Now,

### Testing the Second-Order Necessary Conditions

Obtaing the Hessian matrix of the form:
$[[2,0],[0, 12x_2^2]]$. And the last eigenvalue is not constant? So now, I do not know how to proceed. By definition, it has to be positive semi-definite in order to possibly be an optimiser (or positive definite, then minimum for sure), but here... I do not know what to do.

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to evaluate the Hessian at the origin.

Comment: You can no more solve the problem as formulated here (unless for example you substitute $y=x_2^2$) than you can understand the stationary point of $x^4$ from the first two derivatives alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it is $0$ since $x_1^2\geq 0$ and $x_2^4\geq 0$ and you don't need any fancy stuff like Hessian.

Comment: (+1) Short and correct.

Comment: Just that easy wow. But, in general, having a Hessian that depends upon one of the variables, how would you proceed?

Answer (score 2):

In general :

1-$(0,0)$ is a critical point.
2-in that point(s) if the  Hessian matrix  is positive or negative definite then the point(s) is a local minium or maximum. If not : the  Hessian matrix  has a kernel you cant say any thing.

In your case the  Hessian matrix  is always semi-positive then the function is convex and continuous  and infinite at infinity so it must have a minimum witch must be the critical point.